# android studio not formatting dart code correctlly

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm writing flutter app, and I have this block of dart code

```
  Widget launchScreen() {
    return Screen(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          height: 200, 
                          width: 200, 
                          child: Image.asset("resources/images/logo.png")
                      ),
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
```

which seems very neat and well indented, **but** after running **Reformat Code** in Android Studio, the result is so ugly and stupid

```
  Widget launchScreen() {
    return Screen(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Center(
                child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              Container(height: 200, width: 200, child: Image.asset("resources/images/logo.png")),
            ]))));
  }
```

I tried to update the code style for dart in the settings but I can't find any options to be customized only the line width.

is there a way to improve(fix) the formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart format use the `,` has parameter

```dart
Screen(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.lightBlue,
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Image.asset("resources/images/logo.png"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Your comment helps me from quitting learning Flutter. Before the colons are added, the code style likes from another universe.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try to add , after ] and )
      
   Widget launchScreen() {
    return Screen(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "resources/images/logo.png",
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```